# Testing the sample mean textbook question

Tags: proof-verification, normal-distribution, means, hypothesis-testing

> In each of the following situations it is believed that $X -  N(μ, 400)$. Find the p - value of the observed sample mean. Hence, decide the result of the test if it is conducted at the 5% significance level.
>
> Part a i) $H_0:\:μ\:=85,\:H_1:\:μ\:\ne \:85\: \\n=16\: \bar{\left[X\right]}=95$

My answer was reject $H_0$ as $P(\bar{X}>95) = 0.0228$, and as $0.0228<0.025$ then there is sufficient evidence to reject $H_0$.

However the textbook states reject $H_0$ as the probability is 0.0455 (nothing else is mentioned). Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative hypothesis is double sided, so you also need to account for the case
$$
P(\bar{X}<75)
$$
which is just as extreme, but in the other direction, and by symmetry of the normal distribution the total probability you need is twice $P(\bar{X}>95)$, so

$$
\begin{align}
p &= 2P(\bar{X}>95)\\
&= 2P\left( Z>\frac{95-85}{\sqrt{400/16}} \right)\\
&= 2*0.02275013\\
&=0.0455
\end{align}
$$